# Issue with Facebook integration with AWS Lex : Give bot access to facebook friends

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-apps, facebook-page, amazon-lex

I have created, built and published a sample lex bot.

I followed steps in this link to deploy bot on Facebook messenger. ( by creatign facebook page, fb app and adding webhook etc)
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/fb-bot-association.html

For creating FB app and page I used my Facebook credentials.

**Issue**:
I am able to interact with bot from facebook messenger ( with my facebook account)  and getting desired response from bot

However, when my facebook friend interacts with bot using his facebook account, he doesn't get any response.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your Facebook App is in development mode, so you need to add your friend as a Tester in the role tab, or let Facebook approve your App.

Comment: I have the same problem. In order to go live I need Privacy Policy URL. How to add it?

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to add your friends as Tester or you can publish your app after getting the approval from Facebook.